# A word/name for when multiple people are taking the blame to cover/hide another

Tags: single-word-requests

Like the title.

**Example**

> One kid did something from, and when the teacher asks who it was, all the kids begin to take the blame to cover/hide the kid who did it.

*This also happened in the French Revolution.*

Comment: Hi, and welcome to EL&U. This has all the appearances of a potentially interesting question. However, you need to show basic research, as well as  a sample sentence as required by the SWR tag:"This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.  "

Comment: The "I am Spartacus!" situation. UD shows the origin, but I haven't time now to check how commonly it is used in anger as opposed to jest.

Comment: It's called "herd mentality".

Comment: Sounds a bit like _circlejerk._

Answer (score 0):

You could say collude for multiple people.

Comment: This doesn't demand the blame-taking aspect, but OP does.

Answer (score 0):

How about [collusion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collusion) (M-W): secret agreement or cooperation especially for an illegal or deceitful purpose.

This fleshes out Sabir Aden's response, which lacked a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Those people would be "taking one for the team."

The Cambridge dictionary [defines](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-one-for-the-team) "take one for the team" as:

> to do or experience something unpleasant, or accept blame or punishment for something, so that other members of a group do not have to:
>
> > If somebody has to do it, I'll be glad to take one for the team.